# how can i automatically size listview so it doesn't scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

currently i have the following layout

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 

    android:layout_marginTop="9px" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/desc" 
    android:id="@+id/ll_item"  
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:paddingRight="3px" 
    android:paddingLeft="3px" 
    android:paddingBottom="5px" 
    android:paddingTop="5px" 
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_lists" >
<!--
        <ListView android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:id="@+id/lv"    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:divider="#ddd" android:dividerHeight="1px" android:background="@drawable/white"    />
    -->
    </LinearLayout>
```

the listview that i have commented out, i have tried to make this in the xml, with the height set to wrap_content, fill_parent, currently i am doing this programatically with the following code

```
LinearLayout ll_item = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.ll_item);
        if(list.length() > 0)
        {
            ll_item.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,calcListHeight(list));

            listview = new ListView(this);
            listview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);
            listview.setDivider( new ColorDrawable(this.getResources().getColor(R.drawable.dividercolor)) );
            listview.setDividerHeight(1);
            listview.setCacheColorHint(0);

            mAdapter  = new JSONAdapter( list, this );
            listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ll_item.addView(listview, lp);
        }
```

this is the result

[image]

[image]

so you can see in this image, that since i'm containing the listview in a linearlayout to get the rounded corner look, it doesn't just automatically stretch to contain the entire listview,  is there any way to have the two elements just wrap the content vertically so there is no scrolling without me programatically setting the height ? ? ?

i guess one other thing i should mention is that i have all this layout in a scrollview, because i want this listview to be a tiny subsection of the entire layout, so it would be something like

-scrollview
  -textview
  -textview

  -linearlayout
    -listview

  - button

here is a simpler layout of what i have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/bg" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/titlebar">

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/sv" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bg"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/widget28"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="4dip"
                >


            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" style="@style/rounded_corner_full_width_button"
                          android:id="@+id/editfields">

                <ListView android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:id="@+id/lv" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:divider="#ddd" android:dividerHeight="1px"
                          android:background="@drawable/white"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**ListViews do not go in ScrollViews.**

ListView is for displaying a limited window into unbounded content efficiently. If you were to "disable scrolling" on a ListView to put it within a ScrollView you lose all practical reason for using a ListView in the first place.

If you want to use a ListView to show lots of content or unbounded content but also have content above and below that scrolls with it, add header or footer views to the ListView using [`addHeaderView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View)) or [`addFooterView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)). If the list content is going to be a small portion of your overall layout as you describe, this probably isn't the best approach for you.

If you have a **small, bounded** set of content to present, go ahead and use a ScrollView and programmatically generate child views for your "list items" where appropriate.

A common pattern used in the framework to mix inflated XML content with programmatically generated content is to add a placeholder view in the layout XML, usually a `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout`. Use `findViewById` to locate it at runtime and add generated child views to it.

You could even still use a `ListAdapter` with this approach if you have one written already, just call `content.addView(adapter.getView(position, null, content))` in a loop for all adapter positions (where `content` is the placeholder view you located with `findViewById`). Note that this is only practical if you know that you have a small number of list items in the adapter!

Comment: Thanks Adam, I already had an adapter that I was able to re-use with the LinearLayout using your hint.

Comment: Thanks! Same as Artem I was able to re-use my adapter using a linearlayout instead.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Does your adapter need to be async? When I try this, it only grabs my first item, like the adapter's not done loading.

Comment: Nevermind. All the data is there--it's just showing the last item only. Working on that now.

Answer (score 0):

Add a empty item on list end

Example:

```
ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
String lastItem = "";
int lastPosition;

options.add(lastItem);

public function addItem() {
    lastPosition = options.size() - 1;
    lastItem = options.get(lastPosition);
    options.remove(lastPosition);

    //add new items dynamically
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        options.add("new item: "+i);

    //add empty item
    options.add(lastItem);
}
```