# Is there a way to define a list height as the height of all its items? (Android)

Tags: android, listview, height, scroll, scrollview

I asked this question earlier, but I didn't really understand the only response I got. I'm having some problems writing a program that adds to a list dynamically at runtime. The program has some things above the list and the idea is that the user scrolls down to see the list that the program generates based on the user's input. However, when I use a list it is impossible for the user to see the lower parts of the list because the list takes up a set amount of space and if you try to scroll, the parent ScrollView takes over and assumes that you are trying to scroll the entire activity.

Is there a way to make the List height expand dynamically to wrap the children that are added so that the user can see all of the items in the list while using the Scrollview's scrolling ability? I have tried setting the height to wrap_content, but that did not work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Android engineers have stressed that ListViews should never be put in ScrollViews.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526831/android-scrollview-layout-problem/1528015#1528015) might be of some help to you.

Comment: Yes! Trying to put a ListView into a ScrollView is like trying to tow a car with a bicycle. Check this answer as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506103/how-can-i-automatically-size-listview-so-it-doesnt-scroll/3507199#3507199