# Complex ListActivity Won't Scroll

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-scrollview

I'm having a scrolling issue with a ListActivity.  Here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  style="@style/DefaultBackground" 
  android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/default_header" />

    <ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">   

            <LinearLayout style="@style/RoundedCornerContainer" android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView android:text="@string/is_anyone_injured" style="@style/DefaultText.RoundedContainerImmediateChild" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/accident_help_call_911_btn" android:text="@string/call_911" 
                  style="@style/BaseButton.Large" />                      
                <View style="@style/LandingPageChoiceDivider" />

                <TextView android:text="@string/review_accident_checklist" style="@style/DefaultText.RoundedContainerImmediateChild" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/accident_help_checklist_btn" android:text="@string/checklist" 
                  style="@style/BaseButton.Large" />                      
                <View style="@style/LandingPageChoiceDivider" />

                <TextView android:text="@string/collect_accident_info" style="@style/DefaultText.RoundedContainerImmediateChild" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/accident_help_add_accident_btn" android:text="@string/add_new_accident" 
                  style="@style/BaseButton.Large" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout style="@style/RoundedCornerContainer" android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView android:text="@string/previous_accidents" style="@style/LabelValueTitle" />
                <View style="@style/LandingPageChoiceDivider" />

                <ListView android:id="@id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

                <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/no_previous_claims_found" />                    

            </LinearLayout>         
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my ListActivity:

```
public class AccidentHelp extends BaseListActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AccidentHelp";

    private PreviousClaimAdapter previousClaimsAdapter;
    private List<AccidentInfo> previousClaimList = new ArrayList<AccidentInfo>();   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onCreate called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.accident_help);
            // code for setting up button OnClickListeners here.
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setupPreviousClaimsAdapter();
    }

    private void setupPreviousClaimsAdapter() {

        AccidentInfoDB db = new AccidentInfoDB(getApplicationContext());

        previousClaimList = db.read(currentUser.getUserName());
        //there were no previous accidents.
        if (previousClaimList == null) {
            return;
        }
        previousClaimsAdapter = new PreviousClaimAdapter(this, R.layout.previous_claim_row, previousClaimList);

        setListAdapter(previousClaimsAdapter);
        getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.landing_choice_selector);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.v(TAG, "previous claim selected.");

                AccidentInfo accidentInfo = (AccidentInfo)getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(AccidentHelp.this, ClaimLandingPage.class);
                intent.putExtra(ClaimLandingPage.CLAIM_LANDING_PAGE_ACCIDENT_INFO_EXTRA_NAME, accidentInfo);
                startActivity(intent);                  
            }
        });

    }
}
```

As you can see, I want all the contents of the page except the header to be scrollable. I have successfully done this in non-ListActivities.  However, in this layout, it doesn't allow me to scroll the page at all.

I am updating the list onResume because the data can be updated in sub-activities; regardless, moving that to onCreate doesn't seem to make a difference.
When I remove the `ScrollView`, it allows me to scroll just the ListView portion of the layout.  But I want to scroll the whole page.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListView isn't meant to be inside a ScrollView.  See the answer to [how can i automatically size listview so it doesn't scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506103/how-can-i-automatically-size-listview-so-it-doesnt-scroll).  I am dynamically adding children to an empty LinearLayout in the layout instead.