# android listview doesn't stick on the top of the layout

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have this xml file. The list contains 2 items. When I test the application on the SDK emulator or a tablet, it is displayed as intented. However, when I download the application on a Samsung GT-S5570 with Android v2.2.1, the user can drag the list from the top and move it towards the bottom of the screen. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This may be the default behavior of OS.

Comment: That's what I suspect and I think that the only solution is to use the ScrollView as Paresh's link suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display limited number of items, then put that items within the ScrollView instead of using ListView.

ListView is intended to display unlimited number of items with scrollview to scroll other items.

This answer is the more informative and helpful: [how can i automatically size listview so it doesn't scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506103/how-can-i-automatically-size-listview-so-it-doesnt-scroll/3507199#3507199)

Comment: I understand very well. However I have to add that I've seen the same thing happen to the download manager of the phone's browser as well, so I can't figure out if this is a bad design followed by the android developers or just some behavior fixed in other devices.